# SQL union between NULL and VARCHAR error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, null

I have two views with identical columns. One of the columns on the first view is generated 'on the fly' and set as `NULL` and the same column on the other view has values stored as `varchar`. I have a stored proc that looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mi_GetLearners]  
(@centrename nvarchar(200))  
AS  

SELECT [centrename]  
      ,[Name]  
      ,[Username] --generated on the fly as NULL
FROM  [DB1].[dbo].[vw_Learners]  
WHERE [centrename] = @centrename  

UNION  

SELECT [centrename]  
      ,[Name]   
      ,[Username] --values stored as varchar   
FROM  [Linked_Server].[DB2].[dbo].[vw_Learners]  
WHERE [centrename] = @centrename
```

DB1 is on SQL Server 2008 R2
DB2 is on SQL server 2005

When I run the stored proc I get the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'someusername' to data type int.

Why is it trying to convert the value to int datatype as the other column is set as `NULL`? If I instead change the second column from `NULL` to `' '` the stored proc works fine... I'm really baffled as to why a union between a `varchar` column and `NULL` column generated in a select statement would throw such an error... any ideas?

EDIT: I'm looking for an explanation rather than a solution...

EDIT 2: Running the following code:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_myview
AS
SELECT NULL AS MyColumn

EXECUTE sp_help vw_myview
```

Returns:

```
    Type    Column_name
     int       MyColumn
```

Comment: Post your table definitions, the column datatypes must match for union to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `NULL` is (to within some wiggle room) a member of *every* data type.

When any `SELECT` query is being run, the contents of each column must be of one type, and only one type. When there are a mixture of values in a column (including `NULL`s), the type can obviously be determined by examining the types of the non-`NULL` values, and appropriate conversions are performed, as necessary.

But, when all rows contain `NULL` for a particular column, and the `NULL` hasn't been cast to a particular type, then there's no type information to use. So, SQL Server, somewhat arbitrarily, decides that the type of this column is `int`.

```
create view V1
as
    select 'abc' as Col1,null as Col2
go
create view V2
as
    select 'abc' as Col1,CAST(null as varchar(100)) as Col2
```

`V1` has columns of type `varchar(3)` and `int`.

`V2` has columns of type `varchar(3)` and `varchar(100)`.

Comment: Seems you are right... if you declare a column as NULL within a select statement (eg select null as MyColumn) and you don't cast to any datatype, SQL server decides it's int.

Comment: @sc0rp - yep. You'd hope it would be [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx), but it isn't.

Comment: `sql_variant` values all have an underlying datatype so it would only be an int wrapped up as a variant anyway...

Comment: @MartinSmith - Really? "This data type can also have NULL as its underlying value, but the NULL values will not have an associated base type."

Answer (score 4):

I'd expect the type of the field to be determined by the first SELECT in the union. You may try changing the order of your two selects or change to CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(...)).

Comment: It is not the first `SELECT`. It looks at all branches and if different uses the datatype definition from the branch with the highest datatype precedence. `NULL` on its own is treated as `int` as can be seen by doing `SELECT NULL AS Col INTO NewTable`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to cast to the same datatype:

```
---
AS  

SELECT [centrename]  
      ,[Name]  
      ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Username] 
FROM  [DB1].[dbo].[vw_Learners]  
WHERE [centrename] = @centrename  

UNION  
---
```

Comment: …except it should probably be done in `[DB1].[dbo].[vw_Learners]`'s query.